# Snowflake Query Compilation issue

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am executing snowflake query in springboot. I am getting Sql compilation error.

Java String Query:

```
"   select '1' as AgeGroup, '0-17' as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union " +
            "   select '2' as AgeGroup, '18-34' as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union " +
            "   select '3' as AgeGroup, '35-44' as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union " +
            "   select '4' as AgeGroup, '45-54' as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union " +
            "   select '5' as AgeGroup, '55-64' as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union " +
            "   select '6' as AgeGroup, '65+' as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 "
```

Here only '65+' as ag_label giving error "**unexpected 'as'. syntax error**"

Query on Snowflake side executing as:

```
select 1 as AgeGroup, 0 - 17 as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union select 2 as AgeGroup, 18 - 34 as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union select 3 as AgeGroup, 35 - 44 as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union select 4 as AgeGroup, 45 - 54 as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union select 5 as AgeGroup, 55 - 64 as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1 union select 6 as AgeGroup, 65 + as ag_label from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

I am new to snowflake. Can anyone please help me out how I can correct the syntax.

Regards,
Prabhash

Comment: Since you do not actually need to specify the column labels after the first query you might try dropping the as clauses in UNION s '2' through '6".